# Teradata query "SHOW PROCEDURE dbName.SP_Name;" not return result

Tags: c#, .net, teradata

when calling statement "SHOW PROCEDURE dbName.SP_Name;" on Teradata Database thorugh the code (.net) i get back empty result set.
but when i run this query on the SQL ASSISTANT  with the same credentials, i do receive results...
please note that every other queries on the DB i do get it with no problem.
it came empty only on "SHOW PROCEDURE" command

this is the code:

```
 using (TdConnection cn = new TdConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                cn.Open();                    
                TdCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandTimeout = CommandTimeoutWindow;
                cmd.CommandText = query;

                using (TdDataAdapter da = new TdDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
```

can you suggest an idea..?
thank you

**details:**
Teradata DB version: 14.00.07.16
.NET Data Provider for Teradata: Teradata.Client.Provider, Version=16.10.0.0

Comment: Can you share your .net query ? Also, try putting a breakpoint in .net code to see what command it is sending and result it's receiving.

Comment: thanks. i've added the code. 
i can't put the breakpoint since the problem occur only on customer site..

Comment: Share the code where you call the SHOW PROC command. And you mean to say it's returning values fine when you run at your end ?

Answer (score 0):

Please give the command type as command type. Text

```
cmd.CommandText = query;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

Also try with an extended connection time out.